# Dompdf "No block-level parent found" (enabled html5 parser and removed white space already..)

Tags: php, laravel, dompdf

I've been struggling on this for hours..

I'm trying to generate a PDF from a Laravel view, using Dompdf and the barryvdh wrapper..

Using version 0.8.2 for both. I read the countless posts mentioning enabling the HTML 5 parser (it's done and double-checked with "$pdf->getDomPDF()->get_option('enable_html5_parser')" which returns true). I also read a lot mentioning an issue with white space - I've trimmed EVERY single space/new line/etc I could find between html tags by adding this in the loadView function of barryvdh:

```
$html = str_replace("\n", "", $html);
$html = str_replace("\r", "", $html);
$html = str_replace("\t", "", $html);
$html = trim(preg_replace( '/>\s+</', '><', $html ));
```

I've "dd-ed" the produced $html and checked that there isn't any whitespace inbetween html tags..

And yet I still get the good old "No block-level parent found.  Not good."

So.. pretty much stuck here.. If anyone has an idea on how to debug this further, I'll take any suggestion!

Thanks

Comment: Hi @Buno Please refer this link get idea https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf/issues/389

Answer (score 0):

Alright upon further investigation... the issue seems to be linked to

```
body {
  display: flex;
}
```

So.. no flex body.

Also, seems like dompdf does not support flexbox layout yet anyway, they are rendered as invisible (cf https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/971) so.. here goes my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
public function loadView($view, $data = array(), $mergeData = array(), $encoding = null){
    $html = $this->view->make($view, $data, $mergeData)->render();
    return $this->loadHTML($html, $encoding);
}
```

To:

```
public function loadView($view, $data = array(), $mergeData = array(), $encoding = null){
    $html = $this->view->make($view, $data, $mergeData)->render();
    $html = preg_replace('/>\s+</', '><', $html);
    return $this->loadHTML($html, $encoding);
}
```

in /vendor/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf/src/PDF.php

Notice: `$html = preg_replace('/>\s+</', '><', $html);` in the second one.